# Authorized ASP.NET Web API doesn't give 401 unauthorized error code even when no user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have an api folder and api controller within an MVC project. In the api controller I used  **[System.Web.*Http*.Authorize]** attribute. When I send a get request to the API controller ***from the web browser***, it redirects me to the Log In page. But when I send the request ***via Postman***, it gives me the data, not an error code, even though no user is logged in.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the Postman request have an Authorization header that you have forgotten about?

Comment: No, it's clean.

Comment: Did you roll your own authorization? If so did you step through it in the debugger?

Comment: Postman is extension of Google Chrome. Are you sure about that any user is not logged in Chrome browser ?